# Не обновляется ObservableCollection в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, wpf-datagrid

Есть DataGrid с 2 столбцами (один текстовый, другой ComboBox) к которому привязан ObservableCollection. По нажатию кнопки в DataGrid должна появиться новая строка.

xaml:

```xaml
<DataGrid Name="rDG" ItemsSource="{Binding Provlist}" Height="208" Width="355" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding ima}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="rCC"  Header="Тип" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding idRegtype}" SelectedValuePath="idRegtype" DisplayMemberPath="Regtype_name">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=SpisokRegtypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=SpisokRegtypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="661,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
```

Собственно создание коллекций spisokRegtypes - для заполнения комбобокса, и Provlist - явл. строкой в dataGrid, держащей в себе комбобокс:

```csharp
private ObservableCollection<Regtype> _spisokRegtypes;
private ObservableCollection<RList> _Provlist;

public class RList
{
    public string ima { get; set; }
    public int idRegtype { get; set; }
}

public class Regtype
{
    public int idRegtype { get; set; }
    public string Regtype_name { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<Regtype> SpisokRegtypes
{
    get
    {
        return _spisokRegtypes;
    }
    set
    {
        _spisokRegtypes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<RList> Provlist
{
    get
    {
        return _Provlist;
    }
    set
    {
        _Provlist = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Метод, отвечающий за INotifyPropertyChanged:

```csharp
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Добавление нового элемента по нажатию кнопки:

```csharp
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SpisokRegtypes = new ObservableCollection<Regtype>();
    SpisokRegtypes.Add(new Regtype() { idRegtype = 0, Regtype_name = "Столица"});
    SpisokRegtypes.Add(new Regtype() { idRegtype = 1, Regtype_name = "Регион" });

    Provlist = new ObservableCollection<RList>();
    Provlist.Add(new RList() { ima = "название", idRegtype = 1 });

    rDG.ItemsSource = null;
    rDG.ItemsSource = Provlist;
}
```

По нажатию кнопки успешно создаётся первая строка, но при повторном нажатии - ничего не меняется, как была одна строка так и осталась. Если вручную добавить строки, а потом нажать на кнопку, то ранее добавленные строки исчезнут и останется лишь строка добавленная кнопкой.
Пытался через ItemSource что-то сделать, но в итоге безрезультатно.

Comment: `как была одна строка так и осталась` - ну наверно потому, что вы все время создаете **новый** объект коллекции (`Provlist = new ObservableCollection<RList>();`)?

Comment: У вас в методе логическая ошибка. При каждом нажатии вы заново создаете коллекции, а надо бы проверять, если коллекция уже существует, то просто добавляем новую строку иначе делаем все то, что у вас уже написано в методе.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  и Bulson
Странно, я был уверен что я создаю таким образом экземпляр с помощью которого и можно всё это делать...
А как тогда можно сделать проверку на наличие уже существующей коллекции?

Comment: `new` - новый, то есть это будто у вас 2 листа бумаги, на одном вы написали "привет мир", будут ли изменения на 2-м? Как сделать проверку: Ну самое простое `if (Provlist == null) Provlist = new ObservableCollection<RList>();`. Если эта коллекция не подразумевает быть NULL и вам она нужна постоянно инициализированная, то как вариант сделать просто `public ObservableCollection<RList> Provlist { get; }  = new...`, дальше уже просто добавлять/удалять в нее объекты. Также зачем вы делаете `rDG.ItemsSource = Provlist;`? Вы ведь используете привязки, так задайте один раз `DataContext` и все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Благодарю за разжёвывание новичку. Сделав проверку всё стало нормально работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```csharp
SpisokRegtypes = new ObservableCollection<Regtype>();
```

Вот это надо убрать и использовать только тогда, когда вам надо создать новую коллекцию.

Вместо этого создание новой коллекции в случае если она еще не существует, можно автоматизировать следующим образом:

```csharp
public ObservableCollection<Regtype> SpisokRegtypes
{
    get
    {
        // то же самое что if (_spisokRegtypes == null) return (_spisokRegtypes = new ObservableCollection<Regtype>());
        // else return _spisokRegtypes;
        return _spisokRegtypes ?? (_spisokRegtypes = new ObservableCollection<Regtype>());
    }
    set
    {
        _spisokRegtypes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

В этом случае коллекция будет создана впервые тогда, когда кто-либо к ней обратится (вызовет `get`), а это обычно происходит когда выполняется `InitializeComponent()` у окна, вызов сделает `DataGrid`. То есть, если вы выполняете код после это вызова, то бояться, что коллекция на момент выполнения кода не инициализирована, не придется.