# Как изменить значение Source= ,элемента Image DataTemplate в DataGrid wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-шаблоны

1. Подскажите как изменить значение Source="img/Best/1.png" для ячейки DataGrid на которую нажал, кликом , клавишей, любым вариантом.
2. Как связать  и значение в ячейке DataGrid взятое с DataTables . Пробивал разные варианты, ничего не вышло, сложный wpf для новичка. Очень нравиться кодить, но тут я застрял на 5 дней.

Суть программы для составления схем для вязания: 
Будет "список картинок" и DataGrid, привязная к DataTable. Выбираем картинку (Условное обозначение) и при клике на клетку , нужно присвоить путь картинки в элемент Image, (как бы, рисовать картинкой по клетках).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Скриншот Сетки DataGrid]

На сайт MSDN не отправлять, я там постоянно. 
Как я понял, на WPF так не получиться, возвращаюсь к Windows Forms .

Код XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <viewModel:DataRowViewConverter x:Key="drvc" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ATemplate">
        <Image Source="img/Best/1.png"></Image>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BTemplate">
        <CheckBox ... />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

cs Код:

```
DataGrid MyGrid = new DataGrid();

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add("test", "img/Best/1.png", "img/Best/1.png", "img/Best/1.png");
        dt.Rows.Add("TestString");

        Items = dt;
        this.DataContext = this;

private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate dt = null;
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            dt = (DataTemplate)Resources["ATemplate"];
        else if (e.PropertyType == typeof(B))
            dt = (DataTemplate)Resources["BTemplate"];

        if (dt != null)
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn c = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = dt,
                Header = e.Column.Header,
                HeaderTemplate = e.Column.HeaderTemplate,
                HeaderStringFormat = e.Column.HeaderStringFormat,
                SortMemberPath = e.PropertyName // this is used to index into the DataRowView so it MUST be the property's name (for this implementation anyways)
            };
            e.Column = c;
        }
    }


   public class DataRowViewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = value as DataGridCell;
        if (cell == null)
            return null;

        System.Data.DataRowView drv = cell.DataContext as System.Data.DataRowView;
        if (drv == null)
            return null;

        return drv.Row[cell.Column.SortMemberPath];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите вот [этот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115005). Ваш текущий подход к решению вопроса слишком сложный, в примере предлагается проще, как раз для `DataTable`+`DataGrid`.

Comment: Но есть еще проще пусьт в дополнение к примеру - не использовать `DataTable`, ну только если вы не работаете напрямую с SQL. Вместо этого создать класс для данных, и использовать свойство типа `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`, и к нему уже привязывать табличку, примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092276), но можно еще сотню подобных примеров найти. Попытайтесь разобраться с MVVM, хотя-бы базово, и WPF станет значительно проще в освоении.

Comment: Еще определитесь, а стоит ли использовать `DataGrid`, этот контрол сам по себе не простой и в первую очередь предназначен для редактирования данных прямо в интерфейсе. Вам ведь надо просто отображать? Вот примеры с `ListView`: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090500) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115981)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки буду учить, побывать. 
С помощью данного кода я получаю значение ячейки.
DataRowView drv = MyGrid.Items[0] as DataRowView; 
           MessageBox.Show(drv[2].ToString());
Нужно как-то связать его с <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="Binding ???"></Image>

Comment: Еще раз, я понял, как вы пытаетесь решить, и я не могу подсказать что-либо полезное в этом направлении, потому что написать что-то внятное для работы с контролами напрямую - это сложно, в последний раз я дергал методы и свойства `DataGrid` из обработчиков событий лет 5 назад. А потом узнал про MVVM и `Binding`, и понял, что все это время я "ходил пешком", а можно было "нормально ездить". Вы уже знакомы с `DataContext`, почитайте примеры по ссылкам выше, разберите их, решение само придёт в голову, оно простое.